# Layout Chat bubble

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to create a layout like the whatsapp chat, I have a 9 patch image but I can not do like the image below:
[image]

Currently looks like this:

[image]

My axml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/singleMessage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:text="Hello bubbles!"
    android:textColor="#48026E" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dateTime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:text="00:00"
    android:textColor="#48026E" />
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: @Funkystein my text does not fit the layout, it's like two blocks and not as the first image (whatsapp bubble)

Comment: **1** - Why did you trace a black area in the bubble? **2** - Yes, it's 2 texts, each with its own style. **3** - Your layout is incomplete. **4** - I'd prefer using a RelativeLayout. **5** - assign the bubble 9 patch to the container.

Answer (score 0):

Change the **orientation** of Linear Layout to vertical.
And then move the dateTime textview to right side using **gravity** attribute.

Also change the width of **singleMessage** to **match_parent**

I changed your xml to

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_patch"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/singleMessage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:text="Hello bubbles!"
        android:textColor="#48026E" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="00:00"
        android:textColor="#48026E" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**And it's working exactly as you expected.**

Comment: `fill_parent` is deprecated since API level 8 included. You better use  `match_parent`. Also, where do you set the 9 patch?

Comment: @Funkystein Changed to match_parent. What do you mean by 9 patch?

Comment: 9 patch is the drawable (png) which stretches to fit the contents (the bubble itself).

Comment: @Funkystein Shouldn't that be the background then?

Comment: Of course. Where is it? Supposing it is done in code (to exchange from left bubble and right bubble), **the container should have an id**.

Comment: @Funkystein It's right there, didn't you see. hehee..
Thank you so much for the correction.

Comment: @Funkystein I doubt this was the question. This will need java code as well.

Comment: I can only see ids on the TextViews, not **on the container**. I still see `fill_parent` here and there.

Comment: Yes, it does need Java too. So, I guess this answer not only **has some issues**, but it's also **not complete**